# What is the difference between os.path.basename() and os.path.dirname()?

Tags: python

What is the difference between `os.path.basename()` and `os.path.dirname()`?

I already searched for answers and read some links, but didn't understand. 
Can anyone give a simple explanation?

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Both functions use the `os.path.split(path)` function to split the pathname `path` into a pair; `(head, tail)`.

The `os.path.dirname(path)` function returns the head of the path.

E.g.: The dirname of `'/foo/bar/item'` is `'/foo/bar'`.

The `os.path.basename(path)` function returns the tail of the path.

E.g.: The basename of `'/foo/bar/item'` returns `'item'`

From: http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Comment: Remember that if you replace `item` with `item/`, which is a directory, then `os.path.split('foo/bar/item/')` returns `('foo/bar/item', '')`.

Comment: what will happen if the path is a file, say, "foo.bar"?

Comment: @jkdev Yes, if you want to get the last directory name in a path, you should use: `os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path))`

Comment: @ZhaoGang If the entire path is just a file name, then os.path.basename(file_name) returns the file name: here, `'foo.bar'`, and os.path.dirname(file_name) returns an empty string: `''`.

Answer (score 12):

To summarize what was mentioned by Breno above

Say you have a variable with a path to a file

```
path = '/home/User/Desktop/myfile.py'
```

`os.path.basename(path)` returns the string `'myfile.py'`

and

`os.path.dirname(path)` returns the string `'/home/User/Desktop'` (without a trailing slash '/')

These functions are used when you have to get the filename/directory name given a full path name.

In case the file path is just the file name (e.g. instead of `path = '/home/User/Desktop/myfile.py'` you just have `myfile.py`), `os.path.dirname(path)` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Linux/macOS:

[image: IMG:]

Windows:

[image: IMG:]

Image sources: [Linux/macOS](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-basename/); [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45611368/395857).

---

Note that since Python 3.4, one can use `pathlib.Path`, as explained on [https://miguendes.me](https://miguendes.me/python-pathlib#the-anatomy-of-a-pathlibpath):

Linux/macOS:

[image]

> ```
> >>> from pathlib import Path
>
> >>> path = Path('/home/miguel/projects/blog/config.tar.gz')
>
> >>> path.drive
> '/'
>
> >>> path.root
> '/'
>
> >>> path.anchor
> '/'
>
> >>> path.parent
> PosixPath('/home/miguel/projects/blog')
>
> >>> path.name
> 'config.tar.gz'
>
> >>> path.stem
> 'config.tar'
>
> >>> path.suffix
> '.gz'
>
> >>> path.suffixes
> ['.tar', '.gz']
> ```

Windows:

[image]

> ```
> >>> from pathlib import Path
>
> >>> path = Path(r'C:/Users/Miguel/projects/blog/config.tar.gz')
>
> >>> path.drive
> 'C:'
>
> >>> path.root
> '/'
>
> >>> path.anchor
> 'C:/'
>
> >>> path.parent
> WindowsPath('C:/Users/Miguel/projects/blog')
>
> >>> path.name
> 'config.tar.gz'
>
> >>> path.stem
> 'config.tar'
>
> >>> path.suffix
> '.gz'
>
> >>> path.suffixes
> ['.tar', '.gz']
> ```

---