# os.path.dirname() and os.path.basemane() are giving weird results

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I have recently read about `dirname` and `basename`. My book uses the following image to explain the difference between them:

[image]

I am currently using OSX so my root folder will be /. I wrote the following code in my shell:

```
path='\\Users\\apple\\Documents\\list.txt'
os.path.dirname(path)
```

The result that I got was: `''`

Then I wrote the following code to check the basename:
`os.path.basename(path)` and the result that I got this time was: `'\\Users\\apple\\Documents\\list.txt`!

Whats happening over here? How to fix it?

Also, I don't have any text file whose name is *list*. Shouldn't this cause an error when I was trying to find the `dirname` and `basename` of a file that does not exist!?

Comment: Try Changing path like : `path = r'\Users\apple\Documents\list.txt'` **OR** Use `/` slashes instead of \  .

Comment: paste the exact copy of the lines of code you ran start to finish with the `In[1]` and `Out[1]` from ipython

Comment: OSX does not use backslashes like windows. You probably mean `'/Users/apple/Documents/list.txt'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSX, just like Linux, uses `/` as a separator. You can get the standard separator for your OS from `os.path.sep`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.sep
'/'
>>> path='/Users/apple/Documents/list.txt'
>>> os.path.dirname(path)
'/Users/apple/Documents'
>>> os.path.basename(path)
'list.txt'
```

Notice that [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) is just constructing "correct" paths, it does not do any checking, if files exist. That would not make much sense, if you constructed a path to create a new file. You could use [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) for that.

Comment: That's an amazing answer! Thank You so much

Comment: You're welcome. For more information on "file exists", read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python).