# I have a string that contains the path to a file, how to change the path

Tags: python

I use google clould storage api. I get the filename like this 'pdf/randomPdf.pdf'

I use

```py
new_filename = Path(file_name).stem + ".txt"
```

I do this so I can change the name of the extension to .txt

Now I want to change the 'pdf/...' to 'text/...'

How I can do it without split?

Comment: *"without split"*. Your code (if works) is not using any splits.

Comment: to change the 'pdf/.....' from a string to 'text/.....'

Comment: Please be more clear. Do you want the file to exist in a new location, or want to manipulate the string only?

Comment: What do you have against using split? why does it not work for you?

Comment: if not `split`, maybe `re.sub`?

Comment: `newFilename = filename.replace('pdf/', 'text/').replace('.pdf', '.txt')`

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you very much

Comment: @JohnGordon your solution worked fine, if you want to submit your answer so I can solve the problem

Comment: I've submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the string built-in method `replace()`.

```
newFilename = filename.replace('pdf/', 'text/').replace('.pdf', '.txt')
```

Comment: What about a file called test.pdf.txt.pdf?

Answer (score 3):

These answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272003/what-is-the-difference-between-os-path-basename-and-os-path-dirname) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python) seem relevant to your question -

You can use `os.path.splitext(filename)` to extract everything but file extension - `pdf/pdfFile` in your case.

You can use `os.path.dirname(filename)` to extract the head - `pdf` in your case.

You can use `os.path.basename(filename)` to extract the tail - `pdfFile.pdf` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename)?

Just do

```
os.rename("pdf/pdfFile.pdf", "text/pdfFile.txt")
```